# Showing part of a page only for logged in users

Tags: php, html, cookies

I"m trying to knock up a very a way to show part of a page, only when a user is logged in, using cookies.  Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: `<?php if ($isLoggedIn) : ?> <div id="logged-in-only">…</div> <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: Language? php, asp.. or?

Comment: language: php, using session...

Comment: ok ... I think the tick is big enough that everyone hardly can miss that

Comment: not if you don't know what the tick is there for in first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sessions? http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['example-cookie']))
  show_stuff_for_logged_in_users();
```

And to set cookie use [`setcookie()`](http://www.php.net/setcookie).

Although keep in mind that user can manually set cookies so can't trust them. Using [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Remeber that cookies can be disabled in the browser. Use the $_SESSION variable instead of cookies.

In my Authentication class all users are stored in a database with an access level. On each page the Authentication class uses the $_SESSION variable to get the loged in user and retrieve him/her from the database into a user object. If no one is loged in a default user object for guests are used instead.

In the HTML generation I only check access level before generating "protected" data.

```
if ($User->AccessLevel >= 30) {

  // stuff only available to users with access level 30 and higher

}
```